# Arbitrary Clock Time Calculator

Tags: code-golf, math, date

Create a routine to calculate the position of each unit of a clock with an arbitrary number of units (minutes, hours, half-days, days, years, parsecs, quarter-quells, etc), where each unit can be equally sub-divided into an arbitrary number of sub-units; *after* `n` base units have elapsed.

Basically, figure out what a clock would show after `n` seconds given user defined lengths for minutes, hours, days, etc.

For example, after 86,400 seconds on a clock that has 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, 12 hours per half day, 2 half days per day, and 365 days in a year; you get the following:

`clockFunction(86400,[60,60,12,2,365]) = 0,0,0,0,1`

(Standard Clock)

`clockFunction(86400,[60,60,12,2]) = 0,0,0,0`

(Standard Clock - Rolling Over)

`clockFunction(7430201,[100,100,10,10,3,12]) = 1,2,3,4,1,2`

([French Republican Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_Calendar) [sec / min, min / hr, hrs / day, days / wk, wks / mo, mo / yr])

`clockFunction(2443332,[60,60,24,365]) = 12,42,6,28`

(Standard Clock - Donnie Darko)

`clockFunction(63570500940,[60,60,12,2,365,10000]) = 0, 29, 4, 1, 294, 2015`

(Standard Clock - Back to the Future)

Shortest code that works wins!

Clarifications:

- All Units are integer
- All Units are greater than 0

Comment: In none of the test cases does the last conversion seem to matter at all (eg days/year on the standard clocks). Is this intentional?

Comment: I think that's more how I designed the problems. I used that space as a catch all and made it really big so the biggest unit wouldn't roll over. Final unit does matter. I'll add another example.

Comment: Parsecs measure as much time as light-years...none.

Comment: @brandaemon its a dorky tongue-in-cheek reference to [Star Wars](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20359/kessel-run-in-12-parsecs-screenplay-error-or-part-of-the-movie) :-P

Comment: It's in Star Wars all right, but [parsecs are a real thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec).  I'm very particular about my units.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Dyalog APL, <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
⌽⊤⍨∘⌽
```

This is a dyadic function train that expects seconds and lengths as left and right arguments. It is equivalent to the following, train-less function:

```
{⌽⍺⊤⍨⌽⍵}
```

Verify all test cases at once on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=86400%2086400%207430201%202443332%2063570500940%20%28%u233D%u22A4%u2368%u2218%u233D%29%A8%20%2860%2060%2012%202%20365%29%2860%2060%2012%202%29%28100%20100%2010%2010%203%2012%29%2860%2060%2024%20365%29%2860%2060%2012%202%20365%2010000%29&run).

#### How it works

```
    ⌽ Reverse the right argument...
   ∘    and...
 ⊤⍨     perform mixed base encoding on the left argument with those bases.
⌽     Reverse the order of the result.
```

Comment: Unless someone can get in under 5, winner! Can you explain what your code is doing?

Comment: What encoding does this use?

Comment: @Mwr247 There are APL code pages (that predate Unicode by a few decades) where each character is a single byte.

Comment: @Dennis I figured it was single byte, but for the life of me couldn't find any charset that fit them all. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 10 bytes

```
{{md\}%W<}
```

Verify all test cases at once in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B~%0A%20%20%7B%7Bmd%5C%7D%25W%3C%7D%0A~p%7D%2F&input=86400%20%5B60%2060%2012%202%20365%5D%0A86400%20%5B60%2060%2012%202%5D%0A7430201%20%5B100%20100%2010%2010%203%2012%5D%0A2443332%20%5B60%2060%2024%20365%5D%0A63570500940%20%5B60%2060%2012%202%20365%2010000%5D).

#### How it works

```
{        }  Define a code block:
 {   }%     For each unit length:
  md          Perform modular division with the topmost integers on the stack.
    \         Swap quotient and residue.
            Collect the results in an array.
       W<   Discard the last quotient.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 34 bytes

```js
F=(q,a)=>a.map(u=>[q%u|0,q/=u][0])
```

Explanation:

```js
F=(q,a)=>a.map(u=>
  // For each unit
  [
    q%u|0, // floored remainder of q / u
    q/=u // set q to quotient of q / u
  ][0] // return remainder
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## C – 166 <s>176</s> bytes

The *Back to the Future* test case necessitated using `long long` types! The output format is not consistent in the specs, sometimes there are spaces after the comma, sometimes not, I assumed this meant the space was discretionary. <s>Handles units of zero by outputting `-1`.</s>

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int c,char**v){long long x=atoll(*++v),m;while(--c>1){m=atoll(*++v);printf("%lld%c",x%m,c>2?',':'\n');x/=m;}return 0;}
```

To use, save as `units.c`, compile via `gcc -o units units.c`, and run on the command line as follows:

```
$ ./units 63570500940 60 60 12 2 365 10000
0,29,4,1,294,2015
```

Depending on compiler options, you may be able to remove `int`  and `return 0;` for 153 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 66

```
function a=d(t,L);a=[];for s=L;a=[a mod(t,s)];t=floor(t/s);end;end
```

And an explanation

```
function a=d(t,L)
    a=[];
    for s=L %For each of the input blocks
       a=[a mod(t,s)]; %Append the number in this block
       t=floor(t/s); %And divide by the size of this block ignoring the remainder
    end
end
```

It's a pretty standard approach. I'll see if I can reduce the length.

It also works with **Octave**, so you can try it [here](http://octave-online.net/).

Comment: I did literally the same thing in javaScript. Was curious if anyone had anything fancier or some obscure math trick (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) to do it with.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 47 bytes

```
#~NumberDecompose~Reverse@FoldList[Times,1,#2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X7nOrzQ3KbXIJTU5P7cgvzi1Lii1LLWoONXBLT8nxSezuCQ6JDM3tVjHUEfZKFbtf0BRZl6JgkN6tJmxqbmBqYGBpYmBjkK1GZAAYUMjHQUgMjYzBbINgKA29v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 12 bytes

```
:{:}%:nao-{,
```

Expect (units...,seconds) on the stack.

><> has the oddball property of supporting floating point division but not integer division, so the verbous stack shifting `{}` and copying `:` here is in order to subtract the remainder before performing division.